# Search and Replace string dynamically with concatenated value in xml file

Tags: xml, search, replace, awk, sed

Need to replace string with String plus incremental value in xml file and also need to apply for all files in a directory. This awk command replacing when we know value 'NA' in the element but most of the cases value is not known.

```
awk '/ID>\/{sub(/ID>NA/,"ID>NA"++n)}; 1'
```

File1.xml

```
<ID>NA</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
 ...
<ID>LONEY</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>ZXS01DR</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>QWDRTYYUUU9282</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
```

Expected Result:
File1.xml

```
<ID>NA_1</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
 ...
<ID>LONEY_2</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>ZXS01DR_3</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>QWDRTYYUUU9282_4</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
```

Comment: ExpectedResult:`File1.xml

<ID>NA_1</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
 ...
<ID>LONEY_2</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>ZXS01DR_3</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>QWDRTYYUUU9282_4</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
`

Answer (score 1):

To edit XML files, use a proper XML handling tool. For example, [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh):

```
open File1.xml ;
$n=1 ;
for //ID {
    set . concat(text(), '_', $n) ;
    $n = $n + 1 ;
}
save :b ;
```

Comment: xsh is not setup in our environment

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '/ID>/{$0=gensub(/ID>[^<]+/,"&_"++n,1)} 1' file
<ID>NA_1</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
 ...
<ID>LONEY_2</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>ZXS01DR_3</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>QWDRTYYUUU9282_4</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
```

With other awks you can use match()+substr():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/.*ID>[^<]+/){$0=substr($0,1,RLENGTH) "_"++n substr($0,RLENGTH+1)}1' file
<ID>NA_1</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
 ...
<ID>LONEY_2</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>ZXS01DR_3</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
...
<ID>QWDRTYYUUU9282_4</ID>
<Subject>ASDF</Subject>
```